# Showing that $|f_ng_n-fg|<\epsilon$, where $f_n\to f, g_n\to g$

Tags: real-analysis

The only thing I know about these "algebras" is that they follow the laws of distributivity (for functions and scalars, associativity. I am given that my algebra $A$ is normed, so also know that $||fg||\leq ||f||\ ||g||$.

> $$\ \ \ \text{ If } f_n\to f, g_n\to g, \text{ then } f_ng_n\to fg\in A$$

Ideas:

Since $f,g\in A\implies fg\in A $ since $A$ is an algebra. All that is left to show is that $|f_ng_n-fg|<\epsilon$. Having trouble bounding this in such a way that I can use that $|f_n-f|<\epsilon$ and $|g_n-g|<\epsilon$.

Comment: *hint:* First show: if $f_n$ converges, then $\|f_n\|$ is bounded.

Comment: GEdgar: I know that is true for uniformly convergent $f_n$, but we don't necessarily know that $f_n$ converges uniformly here, do we?

Comment: We know $f_n$ converges in the norm $\|\cdot\|$, right?

Answer (score 2):

A hint:

Copy the analogous proof when the $f_n$, $g_n$, $f$, $g$ are just real numbers.